# Definition of a short

Tags: short-circuit, theory, terminology

I know what a short is, or I think I know. Well maybe I don't.

If two wires from a power source are crossed - it's a short. If a component is working normally - not a short. If the component however uses 50% more than it's nominal current, would it constitute as a short, or 'semi-short'? Is there some threshold in between 0 and 100 % overcurrent in relation to the component itself or the actual circuit, or is it simply determined by the function of the circuit?

Comment: I thought it must've been asked, and there it is. I guess question can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: To be fair, the StackExchange search function is abysmal compared to literally any general search engine.

Comment: It feels like it drops off after a while, tbh. But it was there, and meanwhile a lot of good answers was done here.

Answer (score 4):

An electrical short is when there is a conductor between the two points. So you short VCC pin to the power, the GND pin to the 0V rail and so on. A short isn't a bad thing, it is an electrical connection. It is only a bad thing if you don’t want an electrical connection between the two points.

This means that if a component is working normally there are the correct shorts. There is no such thing as a semi-short. If the current is higher than expected something else is wrong. It may be a short which causes the issue, but without understanding the rest of the system there isn’t much that can be said with confidence. It could be a short between two pins where there shouldn’t be a short, but it could be something else such as the software being wrong, a resistor being the wrong value, a component failure or lots of other options.

Comment: Yeah, semi-short was just made up to illustrate my point with the question. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

In my field of work (semiconductor test engineering), the word "short" is used to refer to any situation where there is substantially more current than there should be. If, for instance, I test a MOSFET and find that there's a whole milliamp of current into the gate at 10 V, that part would be labelled as having a shorted gate. If a 600 V rated part shows over a mA of drain-source leakage at just 300 V, it gets labelled as having a drain-source short.

Note that neither of these are even *close* to what would more commonly be thought of as a short: the hypothetical gate short has an impedance of 10 kΩ, and the drain short 300 kΩ--and the drain short is probably nonlinear, too.

When I need to specify that something has a very low-impedance short (the exact threshold is variable, but I'm talking like less than 10 Ω or so), I'll call it a "dead short". This is sometimes an important distinction, because a dead short implies a different kind of manufacturing fault (usually a problem on a metal layer or a wirebond) than a high-impedance short (usually a problem in the implants, or a flaw in the gate oxide).

Answer (score 2):

As anything in human language, "short" means different things to different people, and different things to the same person in different contexts.

As engineers, we're sometimes a bit spoiled because unlike other disciplines, there's common, well-defined, meanings of *some* words we used. "Short" isn't really one of these words.

I'll still try to say something useful about it, in an attempt of a definition where every word counts.

> A "short" happens when a *source of electrical current* is *shunted* by an *impedance* that is *sufficiently lower* than the source's impedance that the *current that flows as result of that* affects the source's *ability to function* normally

- *source of electrical current*: you can "connect" a source of air to its pump, but it's not what we're talking about. You can also just put an absorber in front of a source of RF power – but that's not shorting, because we're not involving a source of current.
- *shunted*: not a short if we connect the source to something else (for example, if a high-voltage overland line gets damaged and drops to ground: it might have catastrophic effects, but is not a short.)
- *impedance*: this isn't about resistive effects only. Microwave engineers also speak about "shorts" (but again, only if there's a conductor that carries current). You can short an AC source through a sufficiently large capacitor.
- *sufficiently lower* we compare things by magnitude
- *current that flows*: it's not a short if the source just does something nonlinear and no significant current flows
- *ability to function*: that is defining the "sufficiently" in "sufficiently lower": A 100 Ω shunt to ground would short the signal needed to drive a transistor gate in an amplifier, but connected to your mains, it's not a big deal (but a benign, ca. 520 W load)

Comment: it's very interesting to try to tie it down like this, but I think it's likely to exclude things many engineers would call short circuits for "legalistic" reasons.  FWIW, OED gives "An electrical circuit made through a small resistance, esp. one that acts as a shunt to a circuit of comparatively large resistance. "

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that nobody else has suggested this one - how about:

- A short circuit is an *accidental* connection between two points in a circuit that are not supposed to be connected.
- Or sometimes, an intentional connection, made for diagnostic purposes or for entertainment purposes, between two points that are not *normally* supposed to be connected.

Answer (score 1):

A short circuit occurs when the potential difference between two points of an electrical network is zero. It can be real or virtual.
Theoretical electrical engineering establishes that a short circuit is obtained by placing a norator and a nullator in parallel.